# Jooq reactive fetching using r2dbc driver

Tags: jooq, r2dbc

My query looks like (using JOOQ v 3.15):

```
    override fun getCredentialsById(id: Long): Mono<UserCredentialsModel> {
    return Mono.from {
        dsl.select(
                USER_CREDENTIALS.ID,
                USER_CREDENTIALS.EMAIL,
                USER_CREDENTIALS.PHONE,
                USER_CREDENTIALS.LOGIN,
                USER_CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD)
            .from(USER_CREDENTIALS)
            .where(USER_CREDENTIALS.ID.eq(id))
            .and(USER_CREDENTIALS.IS_ACTIVE.eq(true))
            .fetchInto(UserCredentialsModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

JOOQ config:

```
@Bean
fun createContext(): DSLContext {
    return DSL.using(connection)
}
```

where `connection` is `io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory`

and I`m getting an exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Attempt to execute a blocking method (e.g. Query.execute() or ResultQuery.fetch()) when only an R2BDC ConnectionFactory was configured
```

How should I then fetch my query result into Kotlin data class (or Java JOOQ`s POJO) in reactive style?

Comment: Please checkout https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/fetching/reactive-fetching/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  thank you!
I`ve already read the documentation, but there is not clear how to map results of querying into the certain Data class and wrap them into <Mono> in non-blocking way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using jOOQ reactively, you should never call any blocking methods, such as [`ResultQuery.fetchOneInto(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOneInto(java.lang.Class)). That method is just a convenience method for [`ResultQuery.fetchOne()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOne()) and then [`Record.into(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#into(java.lang.Class)). Nothing keeps you from calling `Record.into(Class)` yourself, neither in the blocking world, nor in the non-blocking world.

So, use your usual reactor library methods to map stream contents:

```kotlin
mono.map { r -> r.into(UserCredentialsModel::class.java) }
```

Or, in a complete example:

```kotlin
return Mono.from {
    dsl.select(
            USER_CREDENTIALS.ID,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.EMAIL,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.PHONE,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.LOGIN,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD)
        .from(USER_CREDENTIALS)
        .where(USER_CREDENTIALS.ID.eq(id))
        .and(USER_CREDENTIALS.IS_ACTIVE.eq(true))
} .map { r -> r.into(UserCredentialsModel::class.java) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without testing I would say it should be

```
return Mono.from(
    dsl.select(
            USER_CREDENTIALS.ID,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.EMAIL,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.PHONE,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.LOGIN,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD)
        .from(USER_CREDENTIALS)
        .where(USER_CREDENTIALS.ID.eq(id))
        .and(USER_CREDENTIALS.IS_ACTIVE.eq(true)));
```

Comment: Not sure whether we should use explicit `block()` call if we want to create unblocking database call

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I thought you want to return UserCredentialsModel

Answer (score 0):

You can try .toMono().subscribe()

```
dsl.select(
            USER_CREDENTIALS.ID,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.EMAIL,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.PHONE,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.LOGIN,
            USER_CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD)
        .from(USER_CREDENTIALS)
        .where(USER_CREDENTIALS.ID.eq(id))
        .and(USER_CREDENTIALS.IS_ACTIVE.eq(true))
        .fetchInto(UserCredentialsModel::class.java)
        .toMono().subscribe()
```